# Remove not used Merge tags Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am using C# and writing mail merge application. My users store the templates as follows

```
Dear [[-UserName-]],
You have been subscribed for [[-SubscriptionName-]]...
```

and so on. There will be lot of custom fields between `[[-xxxxx-]]` place holders. I am merging them fine. But sometimes they don't pass for some place holders. I would like to find those things using regular expressions and replace them with empty strings.

Technically, I want to find out the regular expression to find `[[-what ever it is in between-]]` and replace with empty string along with  `[[--]]` tags

Comment: What characters are allowed in the placeholders? Can `-` or `]` characters occur?

Comment: This is my place holder [[-SubscriptionName-]]. Only Alpha numeric characters are allowed between those predefined tags.

Comment: No, but `[[-SomeName-]]` is valid.

Comment: *"Only Alpha numeric characters are allowed"*, so `[[-what ever it is in between-]]` would actually be invalid then?

Comment: Yes, its a metaphor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
\[{2}(-.*?-)\]{2}
# look for [[-, -]] and anything in between.
```

This is called a lazy dot star, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BxlQKg/1).

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no dashes inside the tag names, you can use this regex:

```
\[\[-([^-]+)-\]\]
```

The tag name will be in capture group 1. Obviously, I recommend using the `@""` type of string for the regex.

You will want to use the replacement string:

```
[[--]]
```

Essentially the regex finds `[[-`, then captures a bunch of non `-` characters, then finds `-]]`.